# How to do "meta refresh", but only if the page exists

Tags: javascript

I have a simple SPA used by our team, using angular1.  It gets most of its data from REST calls, but I also have a "meta refresh" tag to occasionally reload the whole page, to make sure the user gets occasional small functionality changes.  There is no need to ever make this optional, it should just reload the page.

The minor annoyance with this strategy is that when the user sometimes disconnects from the network (traveling between work and home, for instance), the page reload fails, and it gets into an error state.  It's easy enough to just force reload the page, but I'd like for this to be a little cleaner, such that it only reloads the page if it can reach the page.

I noticed the advice at https://davidwalsh.name/meta-refresh-javascript .  That uses javascript to do the reload, but it's not conditional on the page existing.

Is there a reasonable variation of this that will simply skip the reload when it can't reach the page, and then reload again when it can?

Comment: impossible to stop a meta refresh from firing in JavaScript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my needs, I ended up implementing a "heartbeat" method in my controller, which calls a Heartbeat service, which does a HEAD request to my REST service, and returns true if the status is 200.

I then call this from the HTML like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.setInterval(function() {
        // Call controller method to call heartbeat service.
        if (angular.element(document.body).scope().heartbeat()) {
            window.location.reload();
        }
    }, 900000)
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `navigator` object has a property `online` that you could check

```
if(window.navigator.online){
  window.location.reload(); 
}
```

Or make an ajax `head` request first and if that succeeds do the refresh

Comment: That last point is an interesting idea.  The HTML is served from the same host that the REST calls are made to, so that might be an effective strategy.  Is "window.navigator" browser-specific?

Comment: navigator is not browser specific. Is also the object that contains geolocation service